# How can access to mysql in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I installed lampp in ubuntu and I can access to phpmyadmin as well but from cmd I can't access, please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Please share the commands output if you are getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try to access MySQL Command Line by executing:

```
 mysql
```

Or

```
mysql -u root
```

Or

```
mysql -u root -p
```